# Generate T2/T1 Phage Resistant E Coli

Tags: bacteriology, transformation

I would like to generate T2/T1 phage resistant Stbl3 E Coli to use in virus production. Is there a plasmid somebody has used that confers resistance, or is this done another way?

Comment: [Two-step resistance by Escherichia coli B to bacteriophage T2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6373494) may not give you a specific protocol as to how to accomplish it, but there may be some useful info